# vectorization of a text file

Tags: java, vectorization

I am trying to implement vectorization of a text file...I have created a dictionary (Unique words in all the documents) ... Which is the best way to implement this in java?

For example - 
My dictionary has the following words - {w1, w2, w3, w4}
And I have 2 documents each having subset of the words in the vocabulary. I need to write to a text file the matrix in the form --

```
1,3,4,0
0,0,2,1
```

Here each row represents a document and the values represent the occurrence of each word in the document.

Can you suggest me the most efficient way to implement this in Java?

Comment: Sure, show us what you have so far though?

Comment: I have stored the Dictionary words in a text file...and I am passing the text string as argument to the function....`public void createVector(String text) throws IOException {String [] x = tweet.split(" ");
  for(String w : x){
   while(((v = reader.readLine()) != null)){...}}}` I am a bit confused as to how to count the number of occurances of each word in the dictionary in the text string.

Comment: You can maintain a dictionary where the key is the word and the value is a count and everytime you encounter that word, increase the count.

Comment: Text vectors are usually very sparse. I think this matrix representation is not very space-efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read in the text file one word at a time
2. Check if the word is already in the dictionary, if it is increase the count
3. Loop through the dictionary outputting the count to the output file.

Because of the homework tag I am giving you the steps and not any actual code(you can find how to do all of this with a quick google search if you dont know how)

Comment: Basically your dictionary is set up with <word, count> and increased each time you find that word.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a HashMap to map each word to the position of that word in a vector. Then each row can be constructed by creating an int[] for the vector, iterating over all words, looking up the position for each word in the map and increment the correponding item.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> dict = new ... // Map word to position
for (String[] doc: docs) {
    int vector[VECTOR_SIZE] = new ....
    for (String word: doc) {
         vector[dict.get(word)]++;
    }
    // Print vector
}
```

Comment: Why use a seperate array instead of just keeping the count in the map? Having a map with the index is just redundant of instead having a map to the count.